# Edit Classpath Variables via Shell Script

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, classpath, rad

Is it possible to edit Eclipse/RAD classpath variables via a shell script?

Background - Enterprise development team with a crazy 40 page word doc setup workspace guide.. Trying to make a shell script to automate most of it.

Is it possible to edit environment settings, specifically this from a setup shell script?

Thanks!